# The reason for using TiN on the perserverance's drill

Tags: materials, mining

Why did NASA use TiN coating for Perseverance's drill instead of coatings like TiAlN, AlTiN, TiAlCrN?

I'm aware of the point of the TiN coating in terms of contamination, but it's a broad topic. Process parameters can be tailored to make a TiAlN coating with minimal roughness, surface energy and also get way better wear characteristics. I was interested if the reason was because of the slightly better anti static behaviour of TiN, reactivity with martian soil or just because it's an old and reliable coating that has been tested million of times by NASA.

Answer (score 7):

I'd prefer a more detailed/scholarly source than this podcast-with-transcription, but the episode [Digging In: When Rovers Get Dirt on Mars](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/27246/digging-in-when-rovers-get-dirt-on-mars/)  of NASA's Mars Exploration podcasts (which I didn't know existed til now) includes an interview with [Aaron Yazzie](https://mars.nasa.gov/people/profile/index.cfm?id=23155), a mechanical engineer at JPL.  Yazzie says:

> Narrator: Perseverance is digging into a part of Mars that may have once been a lake billions of years ago. Scientists are looking here for any evidence that life once existed on Mars, since life on Earth is closely tied to water. The team had to make sure the drilling equipment was the cleanest ever created, because if even the tiniest Earth microbe found its way onto a drill bit, that could introduce false evidence of life in the Mars rock samples.
>
> Aaron Yazzie: The drill bits went through several processes to make sure that they were clean enough to handle our rock samples. So not only did they go through a level of cleaning, but we had to make sure we removed certain layers that, during the machining process, could get covered in oils and could impart certain layers of what they call a recast layer. We had to do some etching to remove all that. We had to do a passivation step to make sure that these bits weren't going to get rusted, basically, when we had them on Mars.
>
> [22:12] And the final step for all the drill bits was to coat them in titanium nitride. Titanium nitride is actually gold in color when you put it on. And its main purpose was to make sure that contaminants didn't stick to those surfaces. They actually put titanium nitride on a lot of drilling equipment here on Earth because it has some properties that helps prevent wear, and so it's a nice hard layer and it doesn't collect particles.
>
> **So it was primarily for cleanliness reasons that we coated it in titanium nitride.** But the nice thing that came out of it is that they're beautiful. (laughs) They’re these beautiful gold shiny bits that just look so futuristic. It's awesome.

Emphasis mine. It's an engineering decision so cleanliness isn't going to be the only reason; there's almost certainly a trade study somewhere, if not for the coatings on the Perseverance / Mars 2020 drills specifically, then certainly for a preceding design. Cleanliness can absolutely be the primary/driving reason though.

A couple articles like [Plasma Nitride Surface Hardening of Titanium for Aerospace and Armament Applications](https://www.mobilityengineeringtech.com/component/content/article/38912-plasma-nitride-surface-hardening-of-titanium-for-aerospace-and-armament-applications) seem to point back to [a Mars 2020 special issue of Tech Briefs](https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/37167-doc-7855) to also support a claim that the titanium nitride coating is to stop contamination from Earth, but I'm not finding relevant quotes online.

I'd asked in a comment that I since deleted which drill you meant; images make it look like they all have the same characteristic TiN gold color. I'm curious about where you heard about the coating *without* it mentioning cleanliness as the reason, because so far all the sources I've found seem to tell the same story.

Comment: One engineering reason is clear from the title of the first article you linked to - it is straightforward to turn a titanium surface into TiN using a nice clean plasma treatment. To get any other alloys you need to get the other constituents into the mix as well. So getting clean uncontaminated TiN is direct, clean, and simple.

Comment: Im aware what is the point of TiN coating in terms of contamination but it's a broad topic. You can tailor process parameters to make TiAlN coating with minimal roughness, surface energy and also get way better wear characteristics. I was interested if it's only a little better antistatic behaviour of TiN, reactivity with marsian soil or just because it's an old and reliable coating that has been tested milion times by NASA.

Comment: @Mikołaj you might want to edit your question to indicate that. I'll keep on looking to see if I find better sources, but as-written I don't see how anyone is supposed to know what you already knew about surface coatings. Your expertise there is clearly beyond mine.